# Mapping legacy model - table only with unique constraint can be used as Domain Class?

Tags: java, oracle, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to map a table (legacy from the Oracle Forms time) that have only a Unique Key, because some values can be null. The user can choose if the data in other applications exists in char or number and the table have the two fields (one varchar2 and other number).

It is possible to use a Domain Class for this?

Example

```
Mytable
---------------------------------------------------------------
office_schedule_id        NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
office_company_char       VARCHAR2(6)
office_schedule_char      VARCHAR2(10)
office_company_num        NUMBER(6)
office_schedule_num       NUMBER(5)
default                   VARCHAR2(1)
```

The unique constraint is composed by all fields except "default".

I've tried this:

```
class OfficeSchedule {
   int officeScheduleId
   String officeScheduleName

   static mapping = {
     version false
     table 'office_schedules'
     id column: 'office_schedule_id', name: 'officeScheduleId'
   }

   static hasMany = [ schedules : IntegrationSchedules ]
}
//this represents MyTable
class IntegrationSchedules {
    String officeCompanyChar
    String officeScheduleChar
    Integer officeCompanyNum
    Integer officeScheduleNum
    String default

    static belongsTo = [ officeSchedule : OfficeSchedule ]

    int hashCode() {
      def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
      //added all fields of the unique key
      builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static mapping = {
      version false
      table 'mytable'
      id composite: ['officeSchedule','officeCompanyChar','officeScheduleChar','officeCompanyNum','officeScheduleNum']
      officeSchedule(column:'office_schedule_id')
    }

}
```

When I try to query, only five of 56 records returns

```
println IntegrationSchedules.findAll().size() //prints 5 but table have 56
```

I tried remove the relation with OfficeSchedule, but still returns just five rows.

I noticed then that the rows that return is because they have all fields informed, that makes sense because I'm defining the key as if it were a PK.

I cannot change the table because are legacy applications that use it.

One workaround that I think is to transfor this as a groovy bean and use a service to create the objects, but with this I cannot use the criteria and GORM findBy methods.

Comment: You are missing a constraints block. Could be the problem since in its absence the fields are by default not nullable. Could you try adding one? Also, if the office_schedule_id is unique that can be your PK alone IMO.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the constraints is just for validation of the domain class. In my case I'm just retrieving data from database. The unique constraint is composed by all fields except "default", so I cannot use the office_schedule_id as PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was, as mentioned by @ideasculptor, to create a hibernate mapping:

src/java/domain

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
class IntegrationSchedules {
    @Id()
    @Type(type="string")
    @Column(name="rowid")
    private String rowid;
    private String officeCompanyChar
    private String officeScheduleChar
    private Integer officeCompanyNum
    private Integer officeScheduleNum
    private String default

    //getters & setters ommited
}
```

And I had to create a hibernate config (hibernate.cfg.xml in conf/hibernate)

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping package="domain" />
        <mapping class="domain.IntegrationSchedules" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The interesting is that dynamic methods of GORM works, eg:

```
IntegrationSchedules.findAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look through the hibernate docs (and do google searches) for a mechanism to map this in plain hibernate.  Once you have a solution in hibernate (and hibernate takes fairly great pains to be flexible so that it can be used on legacy databases), then go back to gorm and try to determine if gorm exposes the same functionality.  At the very least, it may allow you to construct a mailing list query that will generate responses that this one does not.  There is much of gorm that isn't well documented, so getting a sense of how the gorm DSL maps to hibernate configuration is vital for making an educated guess as to how it may be accomplished in gorm